# xamarin.forms project add refrence myproj.uwp.exe throw exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

[when I add refrence xfproj.uwp,error occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzxFp.png)

[xfproj project,debug or build is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Kxm.png)

[xfproj output,I add reference to XFsecond.uwp project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba5CX.png)

when I add refrence (xfproj.Android) to xfsecond.android ,or xfproj.iOS to xfsecond.iOS, it would be fine.  thx ,who can tell me.

Comment: Why are you referencing an app from another app? I don't know if that is supported, but you should usually reference another library instead of whole app. The only place this usually happens is when building unit test apps.

Comment: I think you could not add uwp project to another uwp project. Could you tell me what feature do you want realize?